# Dynamic Method Binding Anomaly?

Tags: java, polymorphism

A very mysterious polymorphism problem:

```
import static java.lang.System.*
class Super{
   public void meth(Super other){
      out.println("#1 - in Super.meth(Super)");
   }
}

class Sub extends Super{
   public void meth(Super other){
      out.println("#2 - in Sub.meth(Super)");
   }
   public void meth(Sub other){
      out.println("#3 - in Sub.meth(Sub)");
   }
}

public class MethodTest{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Super sup = new Super();
     Sub sub = new Sub();
     Super sup_ref_sub = new Sub();

   sup_ref_sub.meth(sub);
  }
}
```

With code above, my output was "`#2 - in Sub.meth(Super)`", whereas I was expecting "`#3 - in Sub.meth(Sub)`", and even more curiously, when I commented out `<public void meth(Super other){...}>`, output changed to "`#1 - in Super.meth(Super)`".

Answer (score 0):

While `sup_ref_sub` is actually a `Sub` because it declared as a `Super` it behaves as a `Super`.

`Super` only has `public void meth(Super)` as its only method; hence why #2 and #3 is printed in your testing.

To get #3 printed declare `sup_ref_sub` as `Sub`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in one thing that the object of actual type will be used to determine the method to be called so in that case we have two options:

```
public void meth(Super other)
public void meth(Sub other)
```

In Java, dynamic method dispatch happens only for the object the method is called on, not for the parameter types of overloaded methods.
Now as per the Java doc:

> When a method is invoked (§15.12), the number of actual arguments (and
>   any explicit type arguments) and **the compile-time types of the
>   arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the signature of the
>   method that will be invoked** (§15.12.2). If the method that is to be
>   invoked is an instance method, the actual method to be invoked will be
>   determined at run time, using dynamic method lookup (§15.12.4).

And now the compile type is of type `Super` so the method invoked will be `public void meth(Super other)`. SO the output for lines:

```
Super sup_ref_sub = new Sub();
sup_ref_sub.meth(sub);
```

will be `#2 - in Sub.meth(Super)`.